# scriptedsandbox64.exe crashes in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have created a standard Apache Cordova App for typescript.

But when I run the debugger with ripple the scriptedsandbox64.exe crashes and when I hit refresh in the DOM explorer the same proces crashes again.

I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 Community today.

It opens in Chrome, how do I get it to open in IE.

Answer (score 1):

I installed IE11 and now it seems to work properly.