# ScriptedSandbox64.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, internet-explorer-11, iis-express

I recently updated my internet explorer from IE 9 to IE 11. Since then, running ASP.NET Web forms application in VS 2015, IIS Express &  IE 11 throws the following dialog.

[image]

Any idea on why this error is occurring?

Note: The issue started occurring after upgrading internet explorer from IE 9 to IE 11.

How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scriptedsandbox64.exe crashes in visual studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238845/scriptedsandbox64-exe-crashes-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Diagnostic Tools, in Options/Debugging/General solved this issue for me.

[image: disable diagnostic tools]